# Problem about the "rdplot" function in package "rdrobust" in R

Tags: r

I am doing a `Regression discontinuity design (RDD)` using package `rdrobust` in R.

For simplicity, my data.frame just have two columns, one is dependent variable `education years`, such as `10,13 (from 0 to 18)`; another one is the running variable `year of birth`, such as `1990,1991…(1963~1999)`and all education years and year of birth are numeric types without NAs.

So I input 
`rdplot(y,x,c=1981)`

because my cutoff is the year 1981, so I add c=1981, it is said that

`Error in chol.default(crossprod(x)):
 the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite.`

But when I rearrange the `year of birth` to make the cutoff as 0. (I generate one new column named `cut_birth` which equals to `year of birth` - 1981). Then it makes the figure successfully.

So I am wondering why the former command failed. Is it just because the year number is too larger or something else?